# is it possible to override doctrine2 persistentobject magic getters and setting

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Can anybody tell me whether its posible to override doctrine2 persistentobject magic getters\setters? i'd like to do the below:-

```
public function setDob($dob)
{
    $this->dob= new \Date($date);
}
```

however my entity is defined as:-

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\PersistentObject;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
* User
* 
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ajfit\Repository\User")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class User extends \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\PersistentObject
{
   /**
    * @var date $dob
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="dob", type="date")
    */
   protected $dob;
}
```

the public function setDob does not get called when I create the entity using:-

```
public function getNewRecord() {
     return $this->metadata->newInstance();
 }
```

I get the below error:-

```
Notice:- array to string conversion ...Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php on line 98
```

Any help would be much apprieciated.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: for what you extend `\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\PersistentObject`?

Comment: to get to the magic getters and setters of the entity, see this blog http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/a-doctrine-orm-odm-base-class, should i not be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__call` of [PersistentObject#__call](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/PersistentObject.php#L219) will not be called if you defined the setDob method.
What you're doing there is creating a new instance via metadata. What you are doing there is probably assuming that `__construct` or any setter/getter should be called by the ORM. Doctrine avoids to call any methods on your object when generating it via metadata/hydration (check [ClassMetadataInfo#newInstance](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L738) to see how it is done) as it does only know it's fields.
This allows you to be completely independent from Doctrine's logic.
About the notice, that is a completely different issue coming from [Doctrine\DBAL\Statement](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php#L98), which suggests me that you have probably some wrong parameter binding in a query. That should be handled separately.